# RHEL 7 how run longtime script before shutdown/reboot systemd

Tags: linux, scripting, rhel, systemd, shutdown

I'm trying to found solution how run script before shutdown/reboot is initiated in RedHat7. I need to correctly shutdown SAP database when I'm shuting down or rebooting server.

Script for SAP shutdown take 3-4minutes, but shutdown of system is very quick -it mean that RedHat kill all proceses imediatly...

my

systemd sap.service is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Shutdown SAP
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/usr/sap/stopsap
RemainAfterExit=true
KillMode=none

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

As I see in shutdown log - database wasnt shutted down correctly:

```
Checking ADA Database
-------------------------------------------
setTrace: false
J2EE Database is not available
```

Can you help me?

Thank you

Ivo

Edit 21.10.2015:

I moved to next step - it is  working better, but still not correctly:

`[Unit] Description=SAP sluzba
After=network.target sshd.target Wants=network.target sshd.service
[Service] Type=simple RemainAfterExit=true
Environment="SAPSYSTEMNAME=RH7" "HOST=cz-brn1-rh7" "HOME=/home/rh7adm"
"PATH=/sapdb/clients/RH7/bin:/sapdb/programs/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/sap/RH7/SYS/exe/uc/linuxx86_64:/usr/sap/RH7/SYS/exe/run:/home/rh7adm:."
 "DIR_LIBRARY=/usr/sap/RH7/SYS/exe/run"
 "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/sap/RH7/SYS/exe/run:/usr/sap/RH7/SYS/exe/uc/linuxx86_64:/sapdb/clients/RH7/lib"
 "RSEC_SSFS_DATAPATH=/usr/sap/RH7/SYS/global/security/rsecssfs/data"
 "RSEC_SSFS_KEYPATH=/usr/sap/RH7/SYS/global/security/rsecssfs/key"
 KillMode=none SendSIGKILL=no TimeoutSec=5min TimeoutStopSec=5min
 User=rh7adm Group=sapsys
     ExecStart=/usr/sap/startsap
     ExecStop=/usr/sap/stopsap

     [Install] WantedBy=graphical.target`

Here is stopsap script:

`#!/bin/bash
date >> /usr/sap/stopsap.log; /usr/sap/RH7/SYS/exe/uc/linuxx86_64/stopsap >> /usr/sap/stopsap.log 2>&1; whoami >> /usr/sap/stopsap.log;`

`J2EE Database is running
See logfile /home/rh7adm/JdbcCon.log
stopping the SAP instance J28
Shutdown-Log is written to /home/rh7adm/stopsap_J28.log
/usr/sap/RH7/J28/exe/sapcontrol -prot NI_HTTP -nr 28 -function Stop
Instance on host cz-brn1-rh7 stopped
Waiting for cleanup of resources..................................................................................................................................................`

and here it stuck for that 5 minutes.. Shutdown script never finish:(

Can I trace how gone shutting down of my sap. service?

Thank you..

Comment: hm, `ExecStart=/bin/true`. How do you start your database?

Comment: Hi, I'm always start database manually with SAP.

Comment: Why do you start it manually? Is SAP a doubleforking process? You can set `ExecStart=cmd-to-start` and remove `Before=`. Unless `DefaultDependencies=` is set to false, service units will implicitly have dependencies of type `Requires=` and `After=` on `basic.target` as well as dependencies of type `Conflicts=` and `Before=` on shutdown.target. These ensure that normal service units pull in basic system initialization, and are terminated cleanly prior to system shutdown.

Comment: I tried, it without `Before` and with `ExecStart=/usr/sap/startsap` but without success.   `su[715]: (to rh7adm) root on none
Oct 09 11:26:19 cz-brn1-rh7 su[715]: pam_systemd(su-l:session): Failed to create session: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.` 

scripts for startsap or stopsap cannot be run as root but as sapadm (in this case rh7adm)

also tried with `DefaultDependencies=false` still without success...

Comment: Try the directive [User=](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#User=). Is `/usr/sap/startsap` a shell script? can you post it?

Comment: anyway, your question is `how to write a service unit for sap`:) not `how run longtime script before shutdown/reboot systemd`:)

Comment: I'm sorry for that - till Rhel 6,5 we used initab for this.. ;)   script for startsap is `su - rh7adm -c "startsap"  >> /usr/sap/startsap.log 2>&1 ` rh7adm is sapsystem user

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the `TimeoutStopSec` value in the unit file. The default is set by `/etc/systemd/system.conf` in the `DefaultTimeoutStopSec` entry (my system has it as 90s). You can set `TimeoutStopSec=0` to disable the timeout entirely (may hang your shutdown if the script doesn't terminate), or pass a larger value that allows the stop script to finish completely.

Comment: Hello, this not worked for me :( 
I'm thinking maybe about some dependencies - its looklike database is already killed when my shutdown script trying to shutdown database...

`reason:         igswd_mt killed by SIGABRT
time:           Fri 09 Oct 2015 09:36:08 AM CEST
cmdline:        ig.sapRH7_J28`

Comment: Also I found this (i tried values 250 or 0, still same):

`sap.service - Shutdown SAPu
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sap.service; enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2015-10-09 10:13:16 CEST; 2min 0s ago
 Main PID: 715 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sap.service

Oct 09 10:13:16 cz-brn1-rh7 systemd[1]: Started Shutdown SAPu.
Oct 09 10:15:16 cz-brn1-rh7 systemd[1]: [/usr/lib/systemd/system/sap.service:5] Unknown lvalue 'TimeoutStopSec' in section 'Unit`

Comment: And by the way: `/etc/systemd/system.conf` are all values commented:
 `#TimerSlackNSec=
#DefaultTimeoutStartSec=90s
#DefaultTimeoutStopSec=90s
#DefaultRestartSec=100ms
 `

Comment: The commented values in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` denote the defaults. If a value there is commented, then it's probably the one in effect through systemd's compiled-in behavior.

Comment: `TimeoutStopSec` goes under the `[Service]` heading, not `[Unit]`.

Comment: Ok, I tried TimeoutStopSec directive, but with no success - database is already killed when script trying to shutdown DB.

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem was in environment:

correct definition of sap.service is:

`[Unit]
Description=SAP sluzba
After=network.target sshd.target
Wants=network.target sshd.service
[Service]
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=true
Environment="HOSTNAME=cz-brn1-rh7" "SAPSYSTEMNAME=RH7" "HOST=cz-brn1-rh7" HOME=/home/rh7adm" PATH=/sapdb/clients/RH7/bin:/sapdb/programs/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/sap/RH7/SYS/exe/uc/linuxx86_64:/usr/sap/RH7/SYS/exe/run:/home/rh7adm:." "DIR_LIBRARY=/usr/sap/RH7/SYS/exe/run" "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/sap/RH7/SYS/exe/run:/usr/sap/RH7/SYS/exe/uc/linuxx86_64:/sapdb/clients/RH7/lib" "RSEC_SSFS_DATAPATH=/usr/sap/RH7/SYS/global/security/rsecssfs/data" "RSEC_SSFS_KEYPATH=/usr/sap/RH7/SYS/global/security/rsecssfs/key"
KillMode=none
SendSIGKILL=no
TimeoutSec=5min
TimeoutStopSec=5min
User=rh7adm
Group=sapsys
ExecStart=/usr/sap/startsap
ExecStop=/usr/sap/stopsap
[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target`

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar need for executing a script prior to my Oracle DB's being shutdown and thought I'd share my findings here in case others come upon this same post looking for a resolution....

To me, it appears that Oracle's oracle-ohasd.service never shuts down the database cleanly.  But regardless of whether oracle db shutdown cleanly or not, I  want my script to execute the DG Switchover and OEM Blackout of this node prior to oracle-ohasd.service being executed.  So here's what I did.

I have two services declared.

WDOracle-shutdown.service -  This handles executing my pre-shutdown scripts.  The key for me to get this to work was adding "Before=WDOracle-shutdown.service" to the oracle provided "oracle-ohsasd.service" and having "After=oracle-ohasd.service" in my WDOracle-shutdown.service.   The "Before, Requires, and RequiresMountsFor" were probably also needed in my WDOracle-shutdown.service, but adding the "Before=WDOracle-shutdown.service" in the oracle provided "oracle-ohasd.service" is the final step that I did to get it working.

WDOracle-db.service - Is the service that removes my OEM blackouts after the server and databases start back up.   It also checks the lifecycle status in OEM and will adjust it according to whether the DB_ROLE is Primary or Physical Standby.

Here are my settings for the 3 services involved.

cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/WDOracle-shutdown.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Oracle Blackout Creation
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target
After=oracle-ohasd.service
Requires=network-online.target network.target multi-user.target oracle-ohasd.service
RequiresMountsFor=/opt/apps/oem /opt/apps/oracle /opt/apps/grid

[Service]
KillMode=none
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/opt/apps/oracle/scripts/WDOracle-db.sh stop
RemainAfterExit=yes
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

cat /etc/systemd/system/WDOracle-db.service

```
[Unit]
Description=WD Oracle Non-Prod DB service
After=network-online.target remote-fs.target autofs.service oracle-ohasd.service

[Service]
User=root
Type=forking
ExecStart=/opt/apps/oracle/scripts/WDOracle-db.sh start
TimeoutSec=0
RemainAfterExit=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

cat /etc/systemd/system/oracle-ohasd.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Oracle High Availability Services
After=network-online.target remote-fs.target autofs.service
Before=WDOracle-shutdown.service
Wants=network-online.target remote-fs.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/init.ohasd run >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/init.ohasd stop >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null
TimeoutStopSec=60min
Type=simple
Restart=always

KillMode=process
SendSIGKILL=yes

StartLimitBurst=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target graphical.target
```